# Назначить hover и click только тому элементу, над которым находится курсор в данный момент

Tags: jquery, iframe, hover, click, find

Есть html элементов с неопределенной вложенностью (родительские и дочерние) у которых один и тот же класс 'block_edit'. Все они находятся в фрейме 'landing-frame'. Собственно вопрос в заголовке темы: как назначить hover и click только тому элементу, над которым находится курсор в данный момент, а не всем блокам включая родителя?
Пытался через $.each сделать, но что-то недопонимаю, может не туда копаю?

```
<iframe id="landing-frame" scrolling="no" src="page.html" style="height: 5581.2px;">
        <section id="home" class="block_edit">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row margin1 block_edit">
                    <div class="col-lg-5">
                        <div class="main_col-1 content_edit">
                            <h1>Nano Lack Ceramic<br></h1>
                            <p>Специальное нанопокрытие для защиты лакокрасочного слоя авто.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row block_edit">
                    <div class="col-lg-7 order-lg-1 block_edit">
                        <img src="nano-lack/img/header_bmv.png" alt="До покрытия Nano Lack Ceramic и после">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-5 margin2 block_edit">
                        <div class="main_col-2 block_edit">
                            <ul>
                                <li class="content_edit">Защита от сколов и царапин</li>
                                <li class="content_edit">Защита от влаги, пыли, грязи</li>
                                <li class="content_edit">Придает машине блеск</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="main_col-3 block_edit">
                            <a href="#" class="main_btn content_edit" data-target="#exampleModalCenter">Узнать подробности</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </iframe>
```

**Я хочу редактировать блоки, на которые навел курсор мыши (при наведении они подсвечиваются бордером, а при клике, этот бордер сохраняется). Так вот, у всех редактируемых блоков имеется один и тот же класс - block_edit. Как ты понимаешь, если навести курсор на дочерний блок, то ховер сработает и на всех родительских, а родительских может быть неограниченное количество, как и дочерних. Я сначала думал временно переименовать классы, чтобы они отличались друг от друга посредством нумерации, но это не дало никакого результата, видимо потому, что работа с фреймом - это тот еще гемор, туда простым DOM не достучаться. Пробовал вот так:**

````
```
// Ищем блоки в iframe с классом block_edit
        let blockEdit = $(this).contents().find('.block_edit');
        // blockEdit.filter(function (index, elem) {
        //     $(elem).addClass('block_edit' + index).removeClass('block_edit');
        //     console.log(elem["attributes"]["class"]["nodeValue"])
        // });
        //console.log(blockEdit.children())
        // перебираем в цикле найденные блоки
        $.each(blockEdit, function(index, value) {
            // Переименовываем классы добавляя к ним нумерацию
            $(value).addClass('block_edit' + index).removeClass('block_edit');
            let classHover = value["classList"][value["classList"].length-1];
            // Как теперь назначить поведение hover только тому блоку, над которым курсор в данный момент?
            $('.' + classHover).hover(function() { // задаем функцию при наведении курсора на элемент
                $('.' + classHover).css('border', '3px dashed #478500');
            }, function(){ // задаем функцию, которая срабатывает, когда указатель выходит из элемента
                $('.' + classHover).removeAttr('style');
            });
            $('.' + classHover).on('click', function() {
                $(this).toggleClass('block_editor');
            });
        });
````

вот тут

`let classHover = value["classList"][value["classList"].length-1];`

как раз получаем все переименованные классы

```
    block_edit14 my.js:743:17
    block_edit15 my.js:743:17
    block_edit16 my.js:743:17
    block_edit17 my.js:743:17
    block_edit18 my.js:743:17
    block_edit19 my.js:743:17
    block_edit20 my.js:743:17
    block_edit21 my.js:743:17
    block_edit22 my.js:743:17
    block_edit23 my.js:743:17
    block_edit24 my.js:743:17
    block_edit25 my.js:743:17
    block_edit26 my.js:743:17
    block_edit27 my.js:743:17
    block_edit28 my.js:743:17
    block_edit29 my.js:743:17
    block_edit30 my.js:743:17
    block_edit31 my.js:743:17
    block_edit32 my.js:743:17
    block_edit33 my.js:743:17
    block_edit34 my.js:743:17
    block_edit35 my.js:743:17
    block_edit36 my.js:743:17
    block_edit37 my.js:743:17
    block_edit38 my.js:743:17
    block_edit39 my.js:743:17
    block_edit40 my.js:743:17
    block_edit41 my.js:743:17
    block_edit42 my.js:743:17
    block_edit43 my.js:743:17
    block_edit44 my.js:743:17
    block_edit45 my.js:743:17
    block_edit46 my.js:743:17
    block_edit47 my.js:743:17
    block_edit48 my.js:743:17
    block_edit49 my.js:743:17
    block_edit50 my.js:743:17
    block_edit51 my.js:743:17
    block_edit52 my.js:743:17
    block_edit53 my.js:743:17
    block_edit54 my.js:743:17
    block_edit55 my.js:743:17
    block_edit56 my.js:743:17
    block_edit57 my.js:743:17
    block_edit58 my.js:743:17
    block_edit59 my.js:743:17
    block_edit60 my.js:743:17
    block_edit61 my.js:743:17
    block_edit62 my.js:743:17
    block_edit63
```

но оно все равно не работает!

Answer (score 0):

Смотри, вот здесь:

```
$.each(blockEdit...)
```

ты начинаешь перебирать все элементы, с классом block_edit (и родительские и дочерние), соответственно ко всем и будет применено то, что описано дальше.
Чтобы этого избежать, можно либо отфильтровать:

```
let blockEdit = $(this).contents().find('.block_edit')
  .filter((el) => el !== *лишний элемент*)
```

либо внутри, перед тем как вешать hover, делать проверку, нужен ли этому элементу hover:

```
if (value === *необходимый элемент*) {...}
```

Comment: А как я отфильтрую, если я заранее не знаю над каким элементом будет hover? Я и пытался назначить им разные классы:

```$(value).addClass('block_edit' + index).removeClass('block_edit');```

Comment: пробовал так:

```blockEdit.filter((el) => el !== blockEdit.children())```

не работает

Comment: т.е. тебе нужно, чтобы hover'а изначально не было и он присваивался, только при наведении?
Я подумал, что ты хочешь повесить его на все элементы, кроме некоторых.
В таком случае, мои познания подсказывают, что это не возможно, т.к. нельзя повешать hover только при ивенте hover, если изначально не назначен hover, но я могу ошибаться.
Как вариант, можно повешать на все элементы hover, в котором будет назначаться новый (нужный тебе) hover.
Можешь описать, к какому результату ты, в итоге, хочешь придти? Возможно есть другое решение.

Comment: Дополнил изначальное описание задачи, постарался расписать как мог )))

Comment: Да, с уточнениями стало понятнее) Ты уже разобрался, но если интересно, то вот [ссылка](https://learn.javascript.ru/bubbling-and-capturing) по этой теме.

Answer (score 0):

Мне помогли, может кому понадобится вдруг - делюсь с вами:

```
// Ищем блоки в iframe с классом block_edit
let blockEdit = $(this).contents().find('.block_edit');
// перебираем в цикле найденные блоки
$.each(blockEdit, function(index, value) {
    (function($){
        $(value).on('click', function(e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            $(this).toggleClass('block_editor');
        });
        $(value).hover(function(e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            $(this).css('border', '3px dashed #478500');
        }, function(e){
            e.stopPropagation();
            $(this).removeAttr('style');
        });
    })(jQuery);
});
```